# Force mobile version of websites, when available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, user-agent

I have this structure

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>            
<script>
 ...
  </script>            
    <frameset cols="50%,50%">            
      <frameset rows="50%,50%">         
        <frame id="a" src="" name="">         
        <frame id="b" src="" name="">       
      </frameset>      
      <frameset rows="50%,50%">         
      <frame id="c" src="" name="">         
      <frame id="d" src="" name="">      
      </frameset>                
    </frameset>   
</html>
```

My goal is to have the results of search engine a in frame with id a, search engine b in frame with id b, etc.

That works well so far. But I get the desktop version, which is hard to see when the screen is divided by 4 and the main window is resized. How do I force the output to be the mobile version?

I tried

```
window.onload = function(){
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
    get: function () { return '<some fake mobile header>'; }
    });        
};
```

yet this didn't work in chrome.

EDIT:

I tried

```
function setUserAgent(window, userAgent) {
    // Works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE9+
    if (navigator.__defineGetter__) {
        navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
            return userAgent;
        });
    } else if (Object.defineProperty) {
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
            get: function () {
                return userAgent;
            }
        });
    }
    // Works on Safari
    if (window.navigator.userAgent !== userAgent) {
        var userAgentProp = {
            get: function () {
                return userAgent;
            }
        };
        try {
            Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', userAgentProp);
        } catch (e) {
            window.navigator = Object.create(navigator, {
                userAgent: userAgentProp
            });
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>Which changes the useragent</strike> Which does not change the real useragent transmitted to the sites in the frames.

Comment: If you only want a "mobile" version, don't have a "desktop" version. User agent sniffing is a horrible strategy, screen size is likely your best bet (but you really don't need it).

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using proper meta tags in the hmtl header tag, 
here is the details about ViewPort and Responsive Design,and this should help you fix the problem

```
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp
```

Comment: I used `<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1"></head>`. Still, same result.

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.

Comment: I dint have enough reputation at that point to leave it as comment, I will learn.